# CSP and PDF ad data-blob in iFrame causes rejection

Tags: reactjs, iframe, content-security-policy

I'm using react to show a client-generated .PDF-blob in an iframe like this:

```
   <iframe src={iFrameSource} title="pdfPreview" ></iframe>
```

iFrameSource contains the blob

It worked fine as it is, but now we want to implement some CSP rules and it stopped working in production.

In the browser console, I get this error:

> Refused to frame '' because it violates the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "frame-src 'self' blob:".

I suspect this to be because somehow react generates an iframe with an empty src, even though i use a state with an initial value..  I could easily be wrong.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, i needed the CSP record to look like this:

```
frame-src 'self' blob: data:
```