# why does my MSE code get `Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3000/ may not load data from blob:...`?

Tags: reactjs, media-source

I'm trying to use the HTTP Media Source Extension API in React + MUI. I have a "camera driver" class that maintains a `MediaSource`, and am linking it to a `video` element.

I'm currently doing this by maintaining the driver as react state, created in an effect. And referring to its `url = URL.createObjectURL(this.src);` from the video element after the driver gets set.

```js
function App() {
  // ...
  const [driver, setDriver] = React.useState<null | Driver>(null);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // ...
    setDriver(driver);
  }, [camera]);
  const videoElement = <video src={driver?.url} autoPlay muted />;
  return (/* ... */ videoElement /* ... */);
```

Full working reproduction [here](https://github.com/scottlamb/repro-blob-error/blob/a1ba3545da4a51532d20e3a574e53b6acae979e5/src/App.tsx#L73).

My code seems to work in Chrome and Safari but fails in Firefox 118.0.1 with the following error in console:

```
Security Error: Content at http://localhost:3000/ may not load data from blob:http://localhost:3000/26794ddf-bbc7-4aec-8eec-d2bc0cd61eef.
```

Why?

If I instead use a `React.useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null)`, and update `videoRef.current!.src` to point to the driver's URL, it seems to work. But I'd like to understand why, so I can know what I'm doing wrong and reliably avoid this problem as I modify and extend this software...

---

edit:

I've also tried adding a `src/setupProxy.js` that sets `Content-Security-Policy`:

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/68172973/23584

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.set({
        'Content-Security-Policy': "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' blob:;"
    });
      next();
  });
};
```

See [exact diff](https://github.com/scottlamb/repro-blob-error/compare/main...csp-header).

I can see in Firefox dev tool's network tab that the header value I set is making it through. Still get the error though.

---

If I use the older React 17-like `ReactDOM.render`, everything works. [exact diff](https://github.com/scottlamb/repro-blob-error/compare/main...render) But obviously I can't stay there forever; I should be using the newer `ReactDOM.createRoot(...).render(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

i am not really much expercienced with the reactjs but think you should consider the following  thing as a try

1. instead of using URL.createObjectURL(this.src) to create the blob URL, use the URL.createObjectURL() method directly on the video file itself so that it ensures that the blob URL is created within the same origin as the video file.
   2.assign the blob URL to the src attribute of the video element using videoRef.current.src instead of driver?.url.
   so pleas give it a try with the above approach.

   import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

   ```
        function App() {
          const [driver, setDriver] = React.useState<null | Driver>(null);
          const videoRef = useRef<HTMLVideoElement>(null);

          useEffect(() => {
            if (driver && videoRef.current) {
              const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
              videoRef.current.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);

              mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', () => {
                const sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer('video/mp4');
                fetch(driver.url)
                  .then((response) => response.arrayBuffer())
                  .then((buffer) => {
                    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', () => {
                      mediaSource.endOfStream();
                    });
                    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buffer);
                  });
              });
            }
          }, [driver]);

          return <video ref={videoRef} autoPlay muted />;
        }
   ```

please run it and let me know if any.

Comment: There's no "video file itself" if I'm understanding correctly. I'm using Media Source Extensions to handle segments of video. In my simplified reproduction, I'm fetching one init segment and one data segment, but in my real project's code I'm getting segments over a WebSocket.

Comment: ok ,i will update you if i have any useful .

Answer (score 0):

This is a... [feature of Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/Sources). If you check the docs, it says (ask me not why), emphasis mine:

> Refers to the origin from which the protected document is being
> served, including the same URL scheme and port number. You must
> include the single quotes. **Some browsers specifically exclude blob and
> filesystem from source directives**. Sites needing to allow these
> content types can specify them using the Data attribute.

The net result is that localhost, when requesting a blob from localhost, is considered **a different source** and therefore needs explicit authorization.

You can try adding "blob:" explicitly in the CSP header; it should work.

I'm not familiar enough with your framework to suggest how, though. Knowing that it was CSP that bit you led me to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73936655/content-security-policy-blocks-video-on-react) (I tried "reactjs CSP"), which might shed further light on the subject.

Comment: So I have tried messing with `Content-Security-Policy` (see edit) but haven't managed to avoid the error. It's possible I'm not getting exactly the right CSP header but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I'm also having trouble understanding why—if this is just a matter of setting the CSP header correctly—updating `videoRef.current!.src` instead works. Or why this used to work prior to a React 18 `ReactDOM.render`->`createRoot` switch ([context](https://github.com/scottlamb/moonfire-nvr/issues/286#issuecomment-1627606649)). So I think there has to be more to it than that.

Comment: What I *can* tell you with certainty is that the "Security Error: ... may not load data..." is 100% CSP generated. For some reasons, in some contexts Firefox *thinks* that `blob` is a different source channel. This other guy had the same problem (with blob data) in a frame: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72004400/csp-and-pdf-ad-data-blob-in-iframe-causes-rejection